# Array Problem help me?

Tags: php, arrays

This my array.... Array is dynamically created?

```
             Array
            (
                [a1]=>'k'
                [a2]=>'a' 
                [a3]=>'w'
                [a4]=>'z'

             }
```

i want

```
             Array
            (
                [a1]=>'k,a' 
                [a3]=>'w'
                [a4]=>'z'

             }
```

merging a1,a2 keys

Comment: How the heck did that 'a' know to join the 'k'? Also, smells like homework - tag it as homework if it is.

Comment: how did the first array got initialized with those values in the first place.. if it's just normal setting, u can do it with k,a too right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this was homework? Here's one solution:

```
<?php

$array['a1'] = $array['a1'] . ',' . $array['a2'];
unset($array['a2']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $YOUR_ARRAY['a1']=$YOUR_ARRAY['a1'].','.$YOUR_ARRAY['a2'];
unset($YOUR_ARRAY['a2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can create nested arrays like so:

```
$a = array(array('a, b'), 'c', 'd');
```

And you can modify that sample accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is your array is dynamically created or do you want only static or on what logic u want to second array based on first array,

otherwise if u give values like below then it will store values

```
Array
    (
        [a1]=>'k,a' 
        [a3]=>'w'
        [a4]=>'z'
     )
```

OR

```
Array
    (
        [a1]=>[a1].','.[a2] 
        [a3]=>'w'
        [a4]=>'z'
     )

unset([a2])
```